# Unknown props 'i' and 'w' in <td> tag?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, datetimepicker

When I use the datetimepicker input-moment component, I get the warning

```
Unknown props `i`, `w` in <td> tag. Remove these props from the element.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlHoM.png)

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code in your post?

Comment: https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/issues/47 / https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/issues/36

Comment: @thirtydot wow!

Answer (score 2):

Do not put props 'i' and 'w' at HTML tags, as React does not like non-standard props at HTML tags.

This has been reported to the author of the library:

- https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/issues/47
- https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/issues/36

For now, your best bet is probably to ignore the (harmless) warning and wait for the maintainer to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answer is helpful at all. You don't know how the OP code looks like, and you're basically just re-iterating what the warning says: *Remove these props from the element*.

Comment: This is so typical situation, so I do not need to look at code indeed.

Comment: I disagree. I don't think OP has put the `i` and `w` props on the `td` element like the warning says. Props can be sent down to children, and I think that's more likely what's happened here. OP has probably somehow incorrectly used the `input-moment` component which in-turn incorrectly passes these props to the `td` somehow. -- Don't just assume stuff.

Comment: thirtydot makes me change my mind, this is not an answer, you are right